# run a sub program when selecting yes on msgbox inside userform

Tags: vba, userform

I currently have a userform that has 3 options on printing. I want to be able to click a button, a msgbox appear with the options "yes" or "no" and if the user selects "yes", then run a sub program that's on sheet 4 (i have 2 sheets that are sheet4 and sheet2).I think the problem with the code right now is with "call slab", VBA inst recognizing the sub program "slab", this is the program that will print out my selected data.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  If MsgBox("Do you want to continue?" & vbCrLf, vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
  Call Slab
  Else
  docmd.Close commandButton_Click


  End Sub
```

Comment: You should read:[Chip Pearsons - Scope Of Variables And Procedures](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/scope.aspx)

Comment: ...all VBA coders should read Chip Pearson's ["everything"](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Topic.aspx) :-)

Answer (score 1):

Declare the `slab` as public and it will be ok:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Select Case MsgBox("Do you want to continue?" & vbCrLf, vbYesNo)
        Case vbYes
            Slab
        Case vbNo
            'nothing
    End Select

End Sub

Public Sub Slab()
    MsgBox "Here is the SLAB"
End Sub
```

Comment: this still doesn't work. I need to run a program that is titled "slab", not open a message box. i have tried to call the sub additionally, and I get an error everytime.

Comment: @DavidEverly - to run the program titled slab, try this `Shell "cmd.exe /S /c C:\path-to-slab\slab.exe` instead of `MsgBox "Here is the SLAB"`.

Comment: @DavidEverly to further clarify this answer, it shows you a functional way to do what you want; when a `MsgBox` response is `vbYes` something happens (in this answers case, a `MsgBox` appears with `"Here is the SLAB"`). You should use the method above and apply it to your application, so replace the `MsgBox "Here is the SLAB"` with whatever code you want to execute.